# como imprimir dos matrices unidas

Tags: c++

mi problema consiste en elaborar dos matrices 2x2 e imprimirlas juntas, mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int matriz1[2][2];
    int matriz2[2][2];
    int contador;
    int contador2;
    for (contador=0;contador<2;contador++){
        for (contador2=0;contador2<2;contador2++){

                    cout<<"digite un numero para la primera matriz en la posicion: ["<<contador<<"]["<<contador2<<"]"<<endl;
                    cin>>matriz1[contador][contador2];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for (contador=0;contador<2;contador++){
        for (contador2=0;contador2<2;contador2++){

                    cout<<"digite un numero para la segunda matriz en la posicion: ["<<contador<<"]["<<contador2<<"]"<<endl;
                    cin>>matriz2[contador][contador2];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for (contador=0;contador<2;contador++){
        for (contador2=0;contador2<2;contador2++){


                    cout<<matriz1[contador][contador2];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    for (contador=0;contador<2;contador++){
        for (contador2=0;contador2<2;contador2++){


                    cout<<matriz2[contador][contador2];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

este codigo en el caso de meter los valores 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 me resulta asi:
12
34
56
78
(cada par encima del otro), pero necesito que quede así:
1256
3478
intente ponerlas juntas en el cout pero me queda de otra forma distinta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo necesitas un ciclo `for` para hacer eso, ya que la dimensión de las matrices son iguales. Mira el primer `for` y considera lo siguiente:

```
for(contador=0;contador<2;contador++){
    for (contador2=0;contador2<2;contador2++){                        
                cout<<matriz1[contador][contador2];
    }

    for (contador3=0;contador3<2;contador3++){  // Este se añadió en el interior del bucle
                cout<<matriz2[contador][contador3];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La manera más fácil y mantenible es usar el bucle `for` de rango:

```
for (const auto &fila : matriz1)
{
    for (const auto &valor : fila)
        std::cout << valor << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Las ventajas de este `for`:

1. No necesitas declarar variables de indizado, las calcula el propio compilador.
2. Si cambia el tamñao de la matriz, no debes cambiar el bucle.
3. Escribes menos código.
4. Es más legible.
5. Es más fácil de mantener.

Podemos hacer una función para imprimir este tipo de matrices:

```
void imprime_matriz_2x2(const int (&matriz)[2][2])
{
    for (const auto &fila : matriz)
    {
        for (const auto &valor : fila)
            std::cout << valor << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Con una función parecida podemos leer datos en una matriz:

```
void lee_matriz_2x2(int (&matriz)[2][2])
{
    int indice{};

    for (auto &fila : matriz)
    {
        for (auto &valor : fila)
        {
            std::cout << "Digite un numero para la primera matriz en la posicion: ["
                      << (indice % 2)
                      << "]["
                      << (indice / 2)
                      << "]\n";

            ++indice;
            std::cin >> valor;
        }
    }
}
```

En este caso, las variables que usamos para acceder a la matriz no son `const` porque queremos modificarlas.

Podemos incluso hacer que estas funciones de lectura y escritura sean plantilla, así funcionarán para cualquier matriz bidimensional:

```
template <typename T, auto FILAS, auto COLUMNAS>
void imprime_matriz(const T (&matriz)[FILAS][COLUMNAS])
{
    for (const auto &fila : matriz)
    {
        for (const auto &valor : fila)
            std::cout << valor << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

template <typename T, auto FILAS, auto COLUMNAS>
void lee_matriz(T (&matriz)[FILAS][COLUMNAS])
{
    decltype(FILAS) indice{};

    for (auto &fila : matriz)
    {
        for (auto &valor : fila)
        {
            std::cout << "Valor para [" << (indice / COLUMNAS)
                      << "][" << (indice % COLUMNAS) << "]\n";
            ++indice;
            std::cin >> valor;
        }
    }
}
```

Con estas funciones, tu código podría quedar así:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int matriz1[2][2];
    int matriz2[2][2];

    lee_matriz(matriz1);
    lee_matriz(matriz2);

    imprime_matriz(matriz1);
    imprime_matriz(matriz2);

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rzVu1PNF7dR69BxY).